# All information possible from an ios touch event

Tags: ios, mobile, sensors, game-development

In terms of an iphone 4s+, could someone list everything that could be monitored/recorded/sensed for a touch to the screen? We know that the time the touch began, ended, and the exact coordinates of the touch can be captured, but are there things in addition to this?  For example, is it possible to estimate the size of the finger creating the touch event, such as in Android's getSize method in MotionEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is everything that is available in a UITouch event:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html

No width of touch, sorry.